# How can I embed errors from Haml::Engine in a web page in production on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security, heroku, error-handling, haml

Part of my app is accessible to me alone when I login as admin.

In `documents#new` and `documents#edit`, I have a `<textarea>` in a form  which I use to write and edit structured text using HAML.

I display the structured text in `documents#show` and `documents#print` via:

```
- engine = Haml::Engine.new(@document.content)
= engine.render
```

On `localhost:3000`, if I make an error in my HAML -- such as indenting with the wrong number of spaces -- I see the error in the browser.

In production on Heroku, this is disabled for security reasons, which is what you'd want.

But I still want to see this particular error in production, as it's actually just a typo in my text, not a vulnerability in my app. Is there some way I can send this HAML rendering error to the browser?

I'm thinking the answer might look something like the following, but I'm not sure what.

```
- begin
  - engine = Haml::Engine.new(@document.content)
  = engine.render
- rescue
  - return ##something??##
- end
```

Even better of course would be to find a way to shove that into a model-level validation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answer was:

```
-begin
  - engine = Haml::Engine.new(@document.content)
  = engine.render
- rescue => e
  = e.message
```